# c# datagridview control

Tags: c#, datagridview, controls

I add control to datagridview after doubleclick (rough code):

```
DoubleClick
{  
    datagridview.Controls.Add(newControl);
    datagridview.ClearSelection();  //to be shure that any of cells are selected
    newControl.Focus();
    newControl.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(newControl_KeyUp);
}
```

and:

```
newControl_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter || e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab || e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
    {
        Commit();
    }
}
```

My new control reacts on Keys.A . but It doesn't react on tab and enter.
When I click enter or tab, only datagridview selected cell changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Tab key make focus move, I will recommend you to work on a lower level if you can:

```
private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control newControl = new MyTextBox();

    dataGridView1.Controls.Add(newControl);
    dataGridView1.ClearSelection();  //to be sure that any of cells are selected  
    newControl.Focus();
}

class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Enter || keyData == Keys.Tab || keyData == Keys.A)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Ok, key = " + keyData);
            return true;///Or false??? return to override the basic behavior
        } 
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
 }
```